# How do I use the celery (java version) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, celery

I am trying to do a tiny poc (a add operation in a celery task) with Kotlin -> celery -> python.

Python->celery->Python is ok. But with https://github.com/crabhi/celery-java and this "wrong" code:

```kotlin
package poc_kotlin_celery                                        
                                                                 
import com.geneea.celery.*                                       
                                                                 
fun main() {                                                     
   val client: Celery = Celery.builder()                         
        .brokerUri("amqp://localhost/%2F")                       
        .backendUri("rpc://localhost/%2F")                       
        .build();                                                
                                                                 
   val args = arrayOf(1, 2)                                      
   val result: AsyncResult<Int> = client.submit("task.add", args)
   val suma: Int = result.get() as Int                           
                                                                 
                                                                 
   println(suma as Int);                                         
}
```

I can not fix the compilation errors:

```sh
$ gradle run

> Task :app:compileKotlin FAILED
e: /home/miguel/code/poc_kotlin_celery/app/src/main/kotlin/poc_kotlin_celery/App.kt: (15, 16): Unresolved reference: AsyncResult
e: /home/miguel/code/poc_kotlin_celery/app/src/main/kotlin/poc_kotlin_celery/App.kt: (15, 42): Not enough information to infer type variable R

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 730ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: If it's an api problem, you should consider report the issue on the repository.

Comment: please post `poc_kotlin_celery/App.kt`

Comment: You need to import `Celeri.AsyncResult`, or qualify it this way in the code